# It is possible to obtain in an amount query sales for the month, quarter and semester mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

It is possible to obtain in a query aggregation the sum of sales for the month, quarter and half or I do each query separately?

No matter, the model, my question is whether you can get all the information in a single query or should I do it separately.

If not, what would be the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specifics of your document fields, this can be done via the aggregation framework, using a combination of `match`, `project` and `group` stages.

As an example, I am going to assume a `Sales` document, with `date` field and an `amount` field, that should be aggregated to get the total sales for a given period (the respective date variables for the month, quarter and half conditionals would need to be defined prior as well, e.g. from the query parameters included in a server GET request)

```
Sales.aggregate()
.match(...include general non-date matches here, e.g. company, etc.)  
.project({
   'month': {
      '$cond': { if: {
         '$and': [
            { $gte: [ 'date', new Date(monthStartDate) ] },                
            { $lte: [ 'date', new Date(monthEndDate) ] },
         ]}, then: 'amount', else: 0
       } 
    },
    'quarter': {
      '$cond': { if: {
         '$and': [
            { $gte: [ 'date', new Date(quarterStartDate) ] },                
            { $lte: [ 'date', new Date(quarterEndDate) ] },
         ]}, then: 'amount', else: 0
       } 
    },
    'half': {
      '$cond': { if: {
         '$and': [
            { $gte: [ 'date', new Date(halfStartDate) ] },                
            { $lte: [ 'date', new Date(halfEndDate) ] },
         ]}, then: 'amount', else: 0
       } 
     }
})
.group({
   _id: '_id',
   month: { $sum: '$month' },
   quarter: { $sum: '$quarter' },
   half: { $sum: '$half' }
})
.exec(function(err, res) {
   if (err) { reject(err) }
   resolve(res)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified the doubt.

Comment: Thanks for providing aggregation-framework solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) which is preferred compared to [map-reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#map-reduce) if it is capable of solving your issue on-hand as it is most often both, more readable and faster.

Of course, how this pipeline looks like depends on the shape of your documents (which I do not know yet) but calculating all three sums at once should be possible with a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage filtering down the documents and a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage doing the sum calculations.
In the `$group` stage you can then use the [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator with nested [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operators to conditionally sum up the values for the month, quarter and half year.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a sales collection with documents

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("579d91a4e474b2af2f1ddc65"), "date": ISODate("2015-06-29T22:00:00Z"), "quantity": 1, "price": 30 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("579d9193e474b2af2f1ddc66"), "date": ISODate("2015-07-28T22:00:00Z"), "quantity": 3, "price": 20 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("579d91a4e474b2af2f1ddc67"), "date": ISODate("2015-08-29T22:00:00Z"), "quantity": 2, "price": 10 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("579d91a4e474b2af2f1ddc68"), "date": ISODate("2015-09-29T22:00:00Z"), "quantity": 4, "price": 15 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("579d919ee474b2af2f1ddc69"), "date": ISODate("2015-11-28T22:00:00Z"), "quantity": 2, "price": 20 }
```

With map-reduce the solution will be

```
var mapFunc = function() {
  date = this.date;
  if (new ISODate("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z") <= date && date <= new ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z")) {
    var totalPrice = this.quantity * this.price;
    if (new ISODate("2015-11-01T00:00:00Z") <= date) emit ("lastMonth", totalPrice);
    if (new ISODate("2015-09-01T00:00:00Z") <= date) emit ("lastQuarter", totalPrice);
    emit("lastSemester", totalPrice);
  }
}
var reduceFunc = function(key, values) {
  return Array.sum(values);
}

db.sales.mapReduce(mapFunc, reduceFunc, { out: { inline : 1 } } );
```

The results are

```
"results" : [ { "_id" : "lastSemester", "value" : 210 },
              { "_id" : "lastMonth", "value" : 40 },
              { "_id" : "lastQuarter", "value" : 100 } ]
```

Though, I don't (and would like to) know  how to achieve it with aggregation for this particular collection.

The only thing thing that comes into mind is to `$group` by month

```
db.corders.aggregate(
  { $match: { $and: [ { date: { $gte: new ISODate("2015-06-01T00:00:00Z") } }, { date : { $lte: new ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z") } } ] } }, 
  { $group: { "_id": { "$month": "$date" }, totalPrice: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } } } } );
```

which gives the results

```
{ "_id" : 11, "totalPrice" : 40 }
{ "_id" : 9,  "totalPrice" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 8,  "totalPrice" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 7,  "totalPrice" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 6,  "totalPrice" : 30 }
```

that should be further processed locally according to the task.